# How does the TTL field work for Unified Logs?

Tags: command-line, logs, console

Running `log stats --overview` yields the following summary of all the logs on a mac.

Comparing the start and end timestamps to the lists of TTLs, I don't understand how these work together. If there are 43k logs with a TTL of 30 days, how does the start and end date of 8 days make sense?

I cannot filter for the ttl field, which makes it more difficult to analyze this situation.

[image]

Comment: Just a guess, as documentation is scarce , but I interpret that as *between day 0 and day 7 (8 days), there were 43K logs created that have a 30 day expiration*.  What situation are you trying to analyze?

Comment: @Allan Trying to analyze how retention works with TTL. There does not appear to be a way to set retention limits or config with these logs.